# background color not changing in css

Tags: html, css, hover

`:hover` does not work. The background of `div` is not changing when hovering on `a`

**Code:**

```css
a:hover div {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">b</a>
<div>c</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `+` css selectore to select sibling of a.

Check this out for more child and sibling selectors : https://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/

Your code selects the **child** element.
You should select the **next sibling**:

```css
a:hover+div {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">b</a>
<div>c</div>
```